# Почему адаптер не получает последние две записи?

Tags: java, android

Код работает без проблем но не отображаются 2 последние записи из 6, то есть question и reply.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();
    datum.put("id", obj.getString("id"));
    datum.put("qid", obj.getString("qid"));
    datum.put("name", obj.getString("name"));
    datum.put("subject", obj.getString("subject"));
    datum.put("question", obj.getString("question"));
    datum.put("reply", obj.getString("reply"));
    data.add(datum);
}

if (data != null) {
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list_layout,
                                new String[]{"id","qid", "name", "subject", "question","reply"},
                                new int[]{R.id.txt0, R.id.txt1, R.id.txt2, R.id.txt3, R.id.txt4, R.id.txt5});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Переведите заголовок вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: А элементы с id `txt4` и `txt5` существуют? Может, ошибку какую-нибудь  выбрасывает?

Comment: Вот я балбес, с быстрой заменой цифр на  пустой символ -"" в layout , не заметил что размер шрифта стал 2dp в элементах с id txt4 и txt5  , вот поэтому не отображались два последние, спасибо за подсказку!